# How can I relabel an xarry DataArray?

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I have a DataArray that looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray (rows: 3, cols: 3)>
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [31, 32, 33]])
Coordinates:
  * rows     (rows) <U5 'row1' 'row2' 'row3'
  * cols     (cols) <U4 'col1' 'col2' 'col3'
```

How can I change the labels to get:

```
<xarray.DataArray (rows: 3, cols: 3)>
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [31, 32, 33]])
Coordinates:
  * rows     (rows) <U5 'rowA' 'rowB' 'rowC'
  * cols     (cols) <U4 'col1' 'col2' 'col3'
```

I try to use `test.rename({"row1":"rowA", "row2":"rowB", "row3":"rowC"})` but it gives me a ValueError:

```
ValueError: cannot rename 'row1' because it is not a variable or dimension in this dataset
```

I take it that rename is just simply meant for dimension names, but if that is the case then the documentation does not make that clear **at all**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the easiest approach currently. It's not as nice as pandas' options for this at the moment, and we'd be interested in making it easier. In particular, we'd be very open to a PR making the documentation clearer per your feedback.

```
In [8]: da = xr.DataArray([1,2,3], coords=dict(a=list('xyz')), dims=['a'])
    
In [10]: da
Out[10]:
<xarray.DataArray (a: 3)>
array([1, 2, 3])
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) <U1 'x' 'y' 'z'

In [9]: da.to_dataset('a').rename(x='x2').to_array('a')
Out[9]:
<xarray.DataArray (a: 3)>
array([1, 2, 3])
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) <U2 'x2' 'y' 'z'
```

Comment: It's certainly nicer than my work around, so I'll take it.

And forgive my ignorance, what is a PR? Is that like an improvement request?

Comment: PR is a Pull Request! A way of anyone editing the documentation (or code) of a library like xarray. https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/